# Outlook SendUsingAccount is null when send drafted mail

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I'm using `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` to get address of sender. But when I try sending a draft mail, the `SendUsingAccount` become null, while `SenderEmailAddress` still has value (but not the email address, it's Exchange property).

So why `SendUsingAccount` is null? And is there any alternative way to get email address of sender?

Comment: Are you writing in c# or vb?

Comment: @AlexHarvey I'm writing in C#

Comment: See my answer, I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SendUsingAccount can be null if the property was not explicitly set. In that case you can fall back to Application.Session.CurrentUser.

Comment: Yes, that works! But one more thing, how about send on behalf of someone else?

Comment: In case of Exchange, SentOnBehalfOfName property will be set.

Comment: In outlook2013 I believe the property is set as expected. I wrote a method which normalizes the mail item with all of the sender info set. I also had to cache all of the account email addresses because rpc calls were bringing the app to a halt on slower connections.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, if SendUsingAccount is null, am I guaranteed that outlook will use Application.Session.CurrentUser as the sender? Is there a case where this is not true? Is this documented?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Microsoft documentation MailItem.SendUsingAccount "property returns Null (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the account specified for the MailItem no longer exists." ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx)) . This may be the problem you are having because you are creating a draft the sendUsingAccount property hasnt actually yet been set.

The way I have always been able to get the sender email address is by using the following code in C#:

```
Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser = sender.GetExchangeUser();
if (exchUser != null)
{
    string SenderEmailAddress = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
}
```

I hope this has helped, as always please comment if you need more info and I can amend the answer :)

Comment: what is `sender`? `mail.Sender` is also null in my case.

Comment: MailItem.Sender will be null until the message is actually sent and moved to the Sent Items folder.